# Thread synchronization of boolean variable

Tags: c++, multithreading

Lets say that i have 2 Thread Methods in a Class `A`. One of those threads is running all the time and is checking if a member variable is set. If this member variable is set to true, then the other thread should be started. The second thread `mThread2` stops itself by checking the variable `mRunThread2`.

The question now is: is a mutual exclusion for the boolean variable necessary? Writing to the variable needs more then one assembly instruction, so on this point i need a sync.

```
class A {
public:
    A() : mRunThread1(true) {
        mThread1 = std::thread(&A::DoWork1(), this);
    }

    ~A() {
        mRunThread1 = false;
    }

    void Start2() { mRunThread2 = true; }
    void Stop2()  { mRunThread2 = false; }

private:

    bool        mRunThread1;
    bool        mRunThread2;
    std::thread mThread1;
    std::thread mThread2;

    void DoWork1() {
        while (mRunThread1) {
            bool lastState = false;
            if (mRunThread2 && !lastState) {
                if (mThread2.joinable()) mThread2.join();
                mThread2 = std::thread(&A::DoWork2(), this);
            }
            lastState = mRunThread2;
        }
    }

    void DoWork2() {
        while (mRunThread2) {
            :::
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. I've gone ahead and rolled back the addition of the new question to keep things correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is simple: use [`std::atomic_bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) that way you don't have to worry about violating the memory model and having undefined behavior. A regular `bool` value is not guaranteed to act correctly under multi-threading conditions. An atomic bool however will act correctly because it is guaranteed to be synchronized if that platform requires it, but that is left to the implementation.